# Windows Filtering Platform

Tags: windows, filtering, platform

Good day.

I had been  going through the documentation on Windows Filtering Platform from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff557104.aspx. Am looking for a function that allows DNS interception and redirection.

Would appreciate someone's help in locating the function. Morealso, is it kernel mode or user mode that can support DNS interception and redirection.

Answer (score 0):

the  functions you are  looking  for is  found in this  documentation : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb451830(v=vs.85).aspx

Look  closely at the   FWPM_LAYER_ALE_AUTH_CONNECT_V4.

In terms  of mode, it is the  kernel mode

https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjepPmk2dbVAhUIqo8KHfY5BGkQFggnMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.microsoft.com%2Fdownload%2F5%2Fb%2F5%2F5b5bec17-ea71-4653-9539-204a672f11cf%2Fkmcode.doc&usg=AFQjCNFyFny1dSHrKO1ZBN495l21NXiNFw

Happy  coding